# Anybody know what editor MediaWiki and Wikipedia are using?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

Just started a Wiki built on MediaWiki and is disappointed with the default editor. Have seen the text editor on MediaWiki and Wikipedia (when editing) and they appear to be the same. I was wondering if anybody knowns what that editor is and how can I install it on my MediaWiki. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 1.18 it is built-in the media wiki installation. You just have to enable it.
Look at [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiEditor).

Answer (score 2):

Personally found my answer, it appears to be within the usability initiative.

read [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUsabilityInitiative)

Comment: It is the [WikiEditor extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor), actually. (It used to be part of the UsabilityInitiative extension, but that is discontinued.)